# Spring boot embedded container

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jhipster

We have to deploy our code to WAS 7.0. We have got our spring boot application to deploy to WAS. 
WAS 7.0 uses the Servelet 2.5 spec and we have to use java 1.6 jdk.

I am having issues with running the junit / integration tests. The embedded container is a tomcat 7. Can I run the tests using a lower version of tomcat or jetty.

Answer (score 2):

JHipster is based on Spring Boot, so it has its [requirements](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/getting-started-system-requirements.html) as a minium.

- You will need a Servlet 3.0 container
- It's going to be difficult to have it work on JDK6

The whole point of JHipster is to have a "modern" application, so making it work on Websphere and JDK6 isn't our original goal.